# XPath issue, trying to extract <li>

Tags: php, html, xpath

Trying to scrape  website (http://www.harikadizi1.com/beni-boyle-sev-60-bolum-tek-parca-19-mayis-2014-izle/). I have successfully scraped the titles, and now im trying to scrape the actual video files, but they're in parts.

The HTML is:

```
<ul id="sgr-npt-summary-61852" class="sgr-npt-summary">
<li class="subpage-1 selected">
<a href="http://www.harikadizi1.com/beni-boyle-sev-60-bolum-tek-parca-19-mayis-2014-izle/">
<div>Tek Part</div>
</a>
</li>
<li class="subpage-2">
<a href="http://www.harikadizi1.com/beni-boyle-sev-60-bolum-tek-parca-19-mayis-2014-izle/2/">
<div>1. Parça</div>
</a>
</li>
```

So, I'm looking to scrape the `<div>` within the `<li>`. Ay suggestions? 
I've tried: `$xpath->query("//ul/descendant::*/text()");`
But it gives me too many results! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: what do you mean `too many results`? What are the results, and what did you expect?

Comment: If there are comments on that particular episode, they also come up in my results because the site uses <ul> for that too..

Comment: figured it out :) $x("//ul[1]/li/a/div/text()");

Comment: @user3658366 Please post an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Says I cant accept for another 8 hours, will do so once I can thanks! Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 5/21/2014 4:58:42 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should also do the trick:

```
//*[@id="video_iframe"]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem is that there's one which is a full episode (Tek Part), and the other tabs is in parts, i.e. parts. So im trying to extract only the "Tek Part, 1. Parca, 2. Parca, 3. Parca..etc". So I need to first retrieve the options, and then retrieve the iframe's in each after that..